# How to ensure a single active Task is always killed and replaced on each call to the method that starts the Task.Run?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core, task

**How can I ensure a single active Task is always killed and replaced on each call to the method that starts the Task.Run?**

The idea is to only ever have 1 future notification waiting to be shown (last caller's), no matter how many times the method (SetFutureNotification) is called (or how rapidly).

When debugging and calling the method (rapidly), let's say, 5 times, I am seeing very odd results.
For example: The 2nd callers Task is running and the subsequent callers tasks are cancelled (exited).

The expected behavior is for the last caller's Task to be running (5th caller) and all previous callers Task's cancelled (exited).

By placing a small delay between each of the 5 test calls (500ms), I get the desired result, however I am wanting to learn the correct approach.

```
public static class NotificationsHelper
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();   

    // Set Future Notification (From outside this class).
    // If called multiple times, the existing task should be killed and a new task replaces it.
    public static void SetFutureNotification(string notificationText, DateTime notificationDateTime, Action<string> notificationAction)
    {

        CancelNotification();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {

            while (!_cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, _cts.Token);

                if (DateTime.Now > notificationDateTime)
                {
                    notificationAction?.Invoke(notificationText);
                    _cts.Cancel();
                }

            }

        }, _cts.Token);

    }

    // Cancel Active Future Notification (From outside this class).
    public static void CancelNotification()
    {
        if (_cts != null && _cts.Token != null && _cts.Token.CanBeCanceled == true)
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:
I reformatted my code to test the proposed answer by Oleg (below) by adding an Id to keep track of the tasks. This confirmed the desired result:**

```
public static class NotificationsHelper
{
    private static int _counter = 0;
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    // Set Future Notification (From Anywhere).
    // If called multiple times, the existing task should be killed and a new task replaces it.
    public static void SetFutureNotification(string notificationText, DateTime notificationDateTime, Action<string> notificationAction)
    {
        _counter += 1;
        var id = _counter.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Method Called: " + id);

        CancelNotification();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cts = _cts; // I'm local cts and will be captured by one task only

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {

            while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);

                if (DateTime.Now > notificationDateTime)
                {
                    notificationAction?.Invoke(notificationText);
                    cts.Cancel();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Task active: " + id);

            }

        }, cts.Token).ContinueWith(t => { Console.WriteLine("Task exited: " + id); });

    }

    // Cancel Notification (From Anywhere).
    public static void CancelNotification()
    {
        if (_cts != null && _cts.Token != null && _cts.Token.CanBeCanceled == true)
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks your intention was to cancel every task before starting new one, and its done almost right - the problem is that every task captures and checks same member variable `_cts` that all tasks share. Even though you `new` it for every notification, after your delay (1000) all of them are aware of only last one you've created. What you need is to have every task to have own copy of cancellation token, the one you would be cancelling on every subsequent task:

```
  public static void SetFutureNotification(string notificationText, DateTime notificationDateTime, Action<string> notificationAction)
{

    CancelNotification();
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cts = _cts; // I'm local cts and will be captured by one task only

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {

        while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);

            if (DateTime.Now > notificationDateTime)
            {
                notificationAction?.Invoke(notificationText);
                cts.Cancel();
            }

        }

    }, cts.Token);

}
```

Now, your cancellation routine (that does not need a change) will be canceling the last task created, and only last task would know about it

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the cancelling the `CancellationToken` will signal only that a cancellation is required to the background task. However that task will continue to run for a certain amount of time, up to a point where the `CancellationToken` is checked and the cancellation is processed.

If you want to make sure the task is fully cancelled, you need to wait for it to finish after you cancel the token:

```
// When starting the task:
_currentTask = Task.Run(async () => ...);


// in Cancel method:
if (_cts != null && _cts.Token != null && _cts.Token.CanBeCanceled == true)
{
        _cts.Cancel();
        // Wait for the background task to finish.
        // Maybe with a try/catch block around it, because it might throw a
        // Cancellation exception
        await _currentTask;
        _cts = null;
        _currentTask = null;
}
```

This should work if you always start and try to cancel background tasks from the same thread (e.g. UI thread). If these operations happen from different threads, you might also need to protect `_cts` and `_currentTask`, e.g. with an awaitable Mutex.

If you don't care about whether the background task is still running, and just want to let it finish at some point of time, then the approach outlined by Oleg Bogdanov with capturing the current CancellationToken in the background task will also work.